# How to throw Error and return value from ResponseString Alamofire

Tags: swift, closures, alamofire

I have a question on throwing errors and returning values from ResponseString Alamofire. In fact, I think this is a problem with specified closures as parameter functions

[image]

```swift
func makeRequest() async throws -> String {
    AF.request("https://example.com")
        .validate()
        .responseString { response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let id):    return id
                case .failure(let error): throw APIErrors.alamoFireError(error)
            }
        }
}
```

How would I go about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire's response handlers (the various `response*` methods) don't support additional error handling. But that's not your fundamental issue, as you're trying to use a completion handler in an async context, which isn't going to work anyway. I suggest you use Alamofire's `async` handling instead.

```swift
func makeRequest() async throws -> String {
  let result = await AF.request("https://example.com")
    .validate()
    .result
 
  switch result {
  case .success(let id):    return id
  case .failure(let error): throw APIErrors.alamoFireError(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: oh my gosh - I did not know this existed. Thank you so much!!